# Using MySQL, I'm attempting to create a table in a db, and then insert into, but am getting a 'syntax' error

Tags: mysql, insert, mysql-error-1064

Here's the create table:

```
create table lawyer_info
(firm_name varchar(100),
firm_url varchar(100),
firm_address varchar(100),
firm_city varchar(100),
firm_state varchar(100),
firm_zip int(5),
firm_phone varchar(12));
```

and here's the insert:

```
insert into lawyer_info ('firm_name','firm_url','firm_address','firm_city','firm_state','firm_zip','firm_phone')
values('Leona Beane','http://www.lawyerlbeane.com/','11 Park Place, Suite 1100','New York','NY','10007','212-608-0919'),
values('Morton S. Minsley','http://www.msmlawfirm.com/','101 Lafayette Street, 10th Floor ','New York','NY','10013','212-346-0849'),
values('Steven K. Schwartz, P.A.,','http://www.stevenkschwartzpa.com/','20801 Biscayne Blvd','Aventura','FL','33180','305-936-8844'),
values('Robert H. Feldman','http://www.lawyers.com/rhfeldman/','3550 North Central Avenue, Suite 1500','Phoenix','AZ','85012','602-265-1074'),
values('Joseph M. Udall, PLC','http://www.udallattorneys.com/','18 East University, Drive,Suite 201','Mesa','AZ','85201','480-222-0398');`
```

What I don't get is why I'm getting:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''firm_name','firm_url','firm_address','firm_city','firm_state','firm_zip','firm_' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column names should be unquoted, or backtick quoted in MySQL:

```
insert into lawyer_info (firm_name, firm_url, firm_address, firm_city,firm_state, firm_zip, firm_phone)
values('Leona Beane','http://www.lawyerlbeane.com/','11 Park Place, Suite 1100','New York','NY','10007','212-608-0919'),
values('Morton S. Minsley','http://www.msmlawfirm.com/','101 Lafayette Street, 10th Floor ','New York','NY','10013','212-346-0849'),
values('Steven K. Schwartz, P.A.,','http://www.stevenkschwartzpa.com/','20801 Biscayne Blvd','Aventura','FL','33180','305-936-8844'),
values('Robert H. Feldman','http://www.lawyers.com/rhfeldman/','3550 North Central Avenue, Suite 1500','Phoenix','AZ','85012','602-265-1074'),
values('Joseph M. Udall, PLC','http://www.udallattorneys.com/','18 East University, Drive,Suite 201','Mesa','AZ','85201','480-222-0398');`
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't quote your attribute names. e.g.,

```
insert into lawyer_info (firm_name,firm_url, etc.)
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm a noob at this stuff. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use normal quotes, but backticks for your colum names... it should be

```
Insert into lawyer_info (`firm_name`,`firm_url`,`firm_address`,`firm_city`,`firm_state`,`firm_zip`,`firm_phone`)
```

Comment: also, there is an extra backtic behind your code, but that could be a stackoverflow thing :)